# Facebook Javascript SDK - Friends List with Picture who has not installed my app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am stuck in one position where i am integrating Facebook javascript SDK. I want to list my friends with their name and picture who has not installed my application.

I will use it where i can then use them to invite via FB.ui dialogue.

I have tried certain things where i am able to get list of friends but not able to distinguinsh them.

Can anyone please pass on knowledge or code for same.

I am trying this but this is not giving me any response.

```
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    //query: 'SELECT pic_square FROM user WHERE uid='+udid  // get picture in other detail
    query: 'SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())'
  },
  function(response) {
    //alert('Your pic is ' + response[0].pic_square);
    alert(response);
  }
);
```

Comment: What all have you tried, can you provide some of your sample Code.
For getting pictures from email id have you tried looking at gravatar?

Comment: i have edit the question with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You trying to retrieve list of users who have your application installed by adding `is_app_user` field to `WHERE` clause that way.

You need to change the query to filter only users who have not installed your application:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE is_app_user = 0 AND uid IN (
  SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
)
```

BTW, you run FQL queries with Graph API and not with REST:

```
FB.api('/fql', {q: 'FQL_QUERY_HERE'}, function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have put the function with FB.api('/fql', {q: 'FQL_QUERY_HERE'}, function(response){
  console.log(response);
})

However it is not returning anything? How can i access this data? I am bit new so can u please advice me points to do so? Thanks in advnace

Comment: `response` is object containing `data` property which is array of objects containing page details. so `response.data[0].pic_square` will hold image URL of first page in results. You can iterate over `response.data` in a loop to process retrieved data.